# Обособление приложения, являющегося названием литературного произведения

Tags: пунктуация, названия

Как правильно написать следующие отрывки:

```
В качестве примера приведу роман А. С. Пушкина(,) "Евгений Онегин".
В качестве примера приведу другой роман А. С. Пушкина(,) "Евгений Онегин".
В качестве примера приведу другой роман этого же автора(,) "Евгений Онегин".
В романе А. С. Пушкина(,) "Евгений Онегин"(,) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы разобраться, опустите "А. С. Пушкина", на пунктуацию оно не влияет.

Получается так:
*В качестве примера приведу роман "Евгений Онегин".

В качестве примера приведу другой роман — "Евгений Онегин".

В качестве примера приведу другой роман этого же автора — "Евгений Онегин".

В романе "Евгений Онегин"...*

Comment: Если "а именно" не подходит, то знак не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть так:
В романе ‟Евгений Онегин” присутствуют...
Моя любимая книга — ‟Евгений Онегин”.
Читая книгу, ‟Евгений Онегин”, он вспомнил молодость.
Я приведу в пример другой роман: ‟Евгений Онегин”. (Здесь ставится тири по, если так можно сказать, официальным правилам, но должно ставится двоеточие.)

В этом последнем предложении интонация такая же, как и при перечислении или двоеточии при бессоюзной связи. У правил пунктуации должны быть отчётливые единые принципы постановки знаков для определённых ситуаций, при одинаковой интонации должен ставится один и тот же знак, — всё это нужно, чтобы люди ставили знаки, не задумываясь, чтобы они понимали то, какой знак нужно ставить в уникальных ситуациях.

То, что лингвисты за сотню лет не исправили такой простой момент, говорит многое о них.

Comment: *но должно ставится двоеточие* — нет, не должно ставится. Двоеточие уместно, когда дальше не что-то короткое. *Читая книгу, ‟Евгений Онегин”, он вспомнил молодость* — нет, так не пойдёт, тогда так: *Читая ту книгу, [а именно] ‟Евгений Онегин”, он вспомнил молодость.*

Answer (score 0):

В 1-м и 3-м предложениях запятая не нужна: здесь название романа действительно *приложение (уточняющее)*. Во 2-м и 4-м нужна: здесь «другой роман» и «Евгений Онегин» — *однородные члены предложения*.